# Странное влияние std::cout на программу

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Есть класс (структура) внешний и внутренний (внутри первого). Сделано для перегрузки оператора `[][]`. В задаче нужно было этим оператором вырезать строку "от" и "до".

Я в мэйне очень много инфы вывожу. Инфа выводиться правильно и без странностей. НО. Если я объявляю `std::cout << nTemp` в `substring` структуре, то вывод сразу же меняется. Исчезают все строки, что я выводил в мэйне и вообще, мне кажется, что программа начинает себя очень подозрительно вести.

```
struct String {

    struct Substring{


//ВТОРАЯ часть
//--------------

     const String operator [](int index) const{
        //Здесь проводим аналогичные операции, как и со String и возвращаем уже конечный String
        int nTemp = index - nPastIndex;
        char SecStr[nTemp+1];
        SecStr[nTemp]='\0';
        //std::cout<<nTemp; // Тут проблемный участок
        strncpy(SecStr, str, nTemp);
        String pStr(SecStr);
        return pStr;
    }


    size_t nPastIndex;
    size_t size;
    char *str;
    char *secstr;

};


//ПЕРВАЯ часть
//--------------


     const Substring operator [](const int index)const{
        //Определяем будущий размер массива и определяем его
        int nTemp = size - index; 
        char SecStr[nTemp];
        SecStr[nTemp]='\0';

            //Копируем строку через string в наш массив и передаем этот массив конструктору,
        // который добавляет его в свои поля. Возвращаем объект в следующую кв. скобку []
        // - то есть в Substring (он выше)
        std::string const szNewStr(str);
        strcpy(SecStr, szNewStr.substr(index, size).c_str() );
        Substring NewStr(SecStr,index);
        return NewStr;
    }


    size_t size;
    char *str;
    char *secstr;
};

//main для тестов
//-----------------

int main(){
    const String s("hello world.");
    String const hello("hello world.");
    std::cout<<hello.str<<" "<<strlen(hello.str)<<std::endl;
    String const hell = hello[0][4];
    std::cout<<hell.str<<" "<<strlen(hell.str)<<std::endl;
    String const ell  = hello[1][4];
    std::cout<<ell.str<<" "<<strlen(ell.str)<<std::endl;
    String const ll  = hello[0][0];
    std::cout<<ll.str<<" "<<strlen(ll.str)<<std::endl;
    String const l  = hello[3][9];
    std::cout<<l.str<<" "<<strlen(l.str)<<std::endl;

    if(strcmp(s[1][4].str, "ell")==0){
    std::cout<<"True"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В общем-то есть класс (структура) внешний и внутренний (внутри первого). Сделано для перегрузки оператора [][]. В задаче нужно было этим оператором вырезать строку "от" и "до". В чем мой вопрос :

Я в мэйне очень много инфы вывожу. Инфа выводиться правильно и без странностей. НО. Если я объявляю "std::cout nTemp" в методе структуры String (подписано как "проблемный участок"), то все строки из мэйна перестают выводиться и вообще программа начинает вести себя очень странно.

Comment: Если нет идей, то был бы рад хотя бы какому-то направлению, почему так может быть при работе с потоковыми IO.

Comment: У вас структура `String` не содержит деструктора и конструктора копирования — вы в курсе, что у вас утечка памяти?

Comment: А как выглядит конструктор `Substring`? Это важно.

Comment: Лучше привести пример полностью. Что бы его можно было скомпилировать и потестить.

Comment: Вот тут полный код + задание в комменах в начале файла. Да, у меня не особо хороший код, наверное. Утечек, вроде, нету (Во всяком случае так говорит тестирующая программа на stepic.org, куда и писал задание) http://pastebin.com/HnHK9BCz g++ -std=c++11 -g main.cpp

Comment: Не надо дописвать *SOLVED* в заголовок поста. Вместо этого стоит отметить тот ответ, который оказался вам полезным, как принятый - V  слева слева от ответа.

Comment: Понял. Сделано. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приступим-с:)

```
String::String(const char *str) {
    size = strlen(str);
    this->str = new char[size];
    strcpy(this->str, str);
}
```

здесь создается буфер по длине равный самой строке. Так как длина явно не сохраняется, то размер буфера нам будет неизвестный. Все другие функции, которые будут работать с этим буфером не смогут определить его размер. Функии вида strcpy надеятся, что в самом конце есть нулевой символ.

И когда Вы потом вызваете в 93 строке код

```
if(strcmp(s[1][4].str, "ell")==0){
    std::cout<<"True"<<std::endl;
    }
```

то strcmp идет в разнос. Он будет сканировать Вашу строку и за пределами ее пока не найдет ноль. А это может быть долго и нудно.

Возьмем другую функцию

```
Substring(const char *str = "", size_t nPastIndex = 0) : nPastIndex(nPastIndex){
    this->size = strlen(str);
    char NewStr[this->size+1];
    strncpy(NewStr, str, this->size);
    this->str = NewStr;
    }
```

здесь в `this->str = NewStr;` копируется указатель на стековую переменную. Что там будет - после выхода из функции - сложный вопрос.

Как минимум, нужно переписать так

```
Substring(const char *str = "", size_t nPastIndex = 0) : nPastIndex(nPastIndex){
this->size = strlen(str);
this->str = new char[this->size+1];
strncpy(this->str, str, this->size);
this->str[size] = '\0';
}
```

И ещё нужно не забыть в деструкторах освобождать память.

```
~Substring(){delete[] this->str;}

String::~String(){ delete[] this->str;}
```

После подобных манипуляций valgrind уже не ругается и утечек нет. Вывод вроде как похож на правду. Но Вы лучше знаете, что оно должно выводить. Но это не значит, что в коде больше нет ошибок.

Если теперь расскоментировать вышеуказанную строку, то вывод "не портится". Единственное, что я добавл, так это `<<std::endl`.

P.S. Если Вы пишете на с++ и не используете API функции, которые требуют хитрых строк, используйте обычные std::string и не выделяйте память через new (а тем более чере malloc).

Comment: Исправил, все заработало. Ух ты! А этот "valgrind" выручает, как я вижу. У меня вкладка открыта со вчерашнего дня, чтобы почитать об этом чуде. Думаю, что мог бы себе сэкономить много времени, если бы посмотрел информацию об утилите раньше. Спасибо огроменное, дружище. Теперь могу спать спокойно, ибо всю ночь потратил, чтобы найти ошибку и в итоге обратился сюда. Всем бобра. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 3):

Проблемы у вас практически везде (нет деструктора, нет копирующего конструктора, открытые поля класса).

Вы не привели код конструкторов `String` и `Substring`, и я подозреваю, что вы там просто копируете переданный указатель во внутреннее поле. Если это так, то вы сохраняете указатель на массив, выделенный на стеке (`char SecStr[nTemp+1];`) после выхода из функции — это катастрофа.

Затем, код `strncpy(SecStr, str, nTemp);` — это тоже катастрофа: вы копируете неинициализированную память (это запрещено) по указателю, не проверяя размер доступной там памяти. То есть у вас указатели на случайные куски памяти, по которым вы пишете случайные данные. Такой код работать не может.

Добавление лишней операции может затереть ваши непонятно где лежащие данные, вот и приводит к проблемам. Но проблема не в `cout`, проблема в управлении памятью.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Я теперь понимаю, что такое поведение было как раз из-за неправильного использования стека. Полезный урок на будущее.

Comment: @LigvestO: Пожалуйста! C++ — небезопасный язык, любая ошибка может сказаться когда угодно, и обычно сказывается позже «необъяснимым образом». (Это одна из причин, по которой он, наверное, самый сложный из всех популярных языков.)

Comment: Зато чувствуешь себя особенным, когда ты один из C++ программистов. :)

Comment: @LigvestO: Это да! :-)